# Async queue operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, queue

I have a queue that is increased by new elements every x seconds.

I want to perform an action on each of the items in the queue. But I want to "consume" one item before I carry on to the next item.
Each item is making an async call that needs to be completed before carrying over to the next item.

I am having issues making this work without blocking the application. Anyone have an example of how this can be done?

Comment: TPL Dataflow does this pretty easily.

Comment: Do you have a simple example of how this can be done

Comment: How do you know when a new item has been added to the queue? Do you get an event, or what?

Answer (score 2):

This seems fairly straightforward. I assume everything is on a single thread. If things are on multiple threads then you have a slightly harder problem, but not much harder.

```
class C
{
  bool busy = false;
  FancyQueue q;
  public C() 
  {
    q = new FancyQueue();
    q.Enqueued += HandleEnqueue;
  }
  Task HandleItem(Item x) { ... }
  async void HandleEnqueue() 
  {
    if (busy)
      return;
    busy = true;
    while (!q.Empty) 
      await HandleItem(q.Dequeue());
    busy = false;
  }
}
```

Suppose the queue is empty. Somehow a new item arrives. The event handler is called. We set the busy flag and extract the item, and await its processing. We return to the message loop. Suppose another item arrives while we are waiting. We enter the handler, but it is marked as busy, so we bail out; we know that the item will be handled in the future. Finally, the first item is handled, so we resume the event handler, and hey, the queue is not empty, so we keep on going; we await handling the next item in the queue.

Once the queue is empty then we set busy back to false and the initial invocation of the event handler completes.

With this plan we never have two dequeued items "in flight" at the same time. Remember, "await" is a point in a workflow where the workflow does not continue *until after the task is complete*.